# Bluemix: how do I create a service?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have a problem when creating a Bluemix service - when I select Create Service for either the language translator or any other service, the page stays loaded and never creates the service. What may be the problem?  Appreciate any help you can give me.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache or logging on from a different browser?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the URL in your screen cap, you are using the old Bluemix console, which is no longer supported. Log into [the new console](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/) using your existing User ID and password, and try creating your service again.